# I have a logic problem in C# leetcode TwoSum. The last case with repeated numbers is returning the wrong index

Tags: c#, logic

The challenge requires that the function should return the two indexes of the two numbers that add up to the target number. It receives an array and returns an array with the two indexes.

My solution:

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    var solution = new int[2];   
    var numsTemp = new int[nums.Length];
    Array.Copy(nums, numsTemp, nums.Length);

    for (int index = 0; index < numsTemp.Length; index++) {
        int currentNum = numsTemp[index];

        for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < numsTemp.Length; innerIndex++) {
            if (Array.IndexOf(nums, currentNum) != Array.IndexOf(nums, numsTemp[innerIndex])) {
                int result = currentNum + numsTemp[innerIndex];
                
                if(result == target) {
                    solution[0] = Array.IndexOf(nums, numsTemp[innerIndex]);
                    int next = 0;

                    if(currentNum == numsTemp[innerIndex]) {
                        next = Array.IndexOf(nums, numsTemp[innerIndex]) + 1;
                    }

                    solution[1] = Array.IndexOf(nums, currentNum, next);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return solution;
}
```

The above code works very well with the other cases with different numbers. But with the array `{3, 3}`, it returns the the wrong indexes.

In the line `if(currentNum == numsTemp[innerIndex])` I change the value inside the "if block" for `next` variable so when `solution[1]` index is assigned the code looks for the next index, and doesn't return the index of the first 3 again, apparently it doesn't work. Somebody can help me what's wrong?

Comment: [Here's a dotnetfiddle for the problem](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOI6ON)

Comment: `for (int innerIndex = index + 1; innerIndex < numsTemp.Length; innerIndex++)`

Answer (score 0):

The classic solution uses some kind of *hash table*, say `Dictionary`:

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
  if (nums is null)
    return new [] {-1, -1};

  Dictionary<int, int> known = new();  

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i) {
    if (known.TryGetValue(target - nums[i], out int index))
      return new [] {index, i};

    known.TryAdd(nums[i], i);
  }

  return new [] {-1, -1};
}
```

If you want to implement nested loops solution then note that inner index must be greater than outer one; in your code it can be

```
for (int innerIndex = index + 1; innerIndex < numsTemp.Length; innerIndex++)
```

Then you should add up `nums` items, not indexes etc. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z95VPc)

Simplified Code

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
  if (nums is null)
    return new [] {-1, -1};

  for (int outer = 0; outer < nums.Length; ++outer)
    for (int inner = outer + 1; inner < nums.Length; ++inner) 
      if (nums[inner] + nums[outer] == target)
        return new [] { outer, inner };

  return new [] {-1, -1};  
}
```